# show date from json without all the title

Tags: android, json

i have a probleme , i try to show date from a webservice , and it show all the date ,
for example `"23 mai 2013 11:05:01 GMT"` 
and i want to show for example  just like this  `"today at 9h30"` , 
this is what i make :

```
public Date getDate() { 
        return pubdate;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            this.pubdate = fmt.parse(date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        TextView textedate= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textArticleDate);
        txtArticleDate.setText(article.getDate().toGMTString());
```

what can i do to show just like today or yesterday at ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is just an example ... try it

```
 public class StackExampleDate {

Date pubdate;

public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        setDate("23 mai 2013 11:05:01 GMT");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Date getDate() { 
    return pubdate;
}

public static void setDate(String date) throws ParseException {
    //MMMM = Month as text , z = time zone, ' = character for text
    SimpleDateFormat fmt_in = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    SimpleDateFormat fmt_out = new SimpleDateFormat("'at' H'h'mm");

    Date date_in = fmt_in.parse(date);
    String output_date_string = fmt_out.format(date_in);

    if(isToday(date_in)){
        System.out.println("today "+output_date_string);

    }else{
        System.out.println("Some day "+output_date_string);
    }
}

public static boolean isToday(Date date) {
    return isSameDay(date, Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
}

public static boolean isSameDay(Date date1, Date date2) {
    if (date1 == null || date2 == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The dates must not be null");
    }
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(date1);
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTime(date2);
    return isSameDay(cal1, cal2);
}

public static boolean isSameDay(Calendar cal1, Calendar cal2) {
    if (cal1 == null || cal2 == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The dates must not be null");
    }
    return (cal1.get(Calendar.ERA) == cal2.get(Calendar.ERA) &&
            cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
            cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    }
}
```

//if the result time is another than your given time .. look at your timezone GMT+n

Comment: Hi i meed help here please, so then to display reault in text view i should do this: tv.setText(getDate()); or what,

Answer (score 0):

Using SimpleDateFormat class you can't display today or yesterday. You have to use string operations and get the date, year and compare to the system date, year and create your own string.

**Getting system date** - `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE);`

Answer (score 0):

you need a second dateformater .. for example

```
 String strDate = "12/12/07";

try
{
  //create SimpleDateFormat object with source string date format
  SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");

  //parse the string into Date object
  Date date = sdfSource.parse(strDate);

  //create SimpleDateFormat object with desired date format
  SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss");

  //parse the date into another format
  strDate = sdfDestination.format(date);

  System.out.println("Date is converted from dd/MM/yy format to MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
  System.out.println("Converted date is : " + strDate);

}
catch(ParseException pe)
{
  System.out.println("Parse Exception : " + pe);
}
```

and for "today" something like  if(date==today) than show the string "today at" else than schow the complete date ..

Comment: and should i let this classe or change all of it or what should i do ?